# postgresql pgbadger error - can not load incompatible binary data, binary file is from version < 4.0

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger

I am trying to use **pgbadger** to make html report for postgres slow query log files. My postgres logfiles are in csvlog format in folder pg_log. I transfer all logfiles
(80 files with 10 MB each) to my local windows machine and trying to generate single html report for all files. I created all one file from all files in below way,

```
type postgresql-2020-06-18_075333.csv > postgresql.csv
type postgresql-2020-06-18_080011.csv >> postgresql.csv
....
....
type postgresql-2020-06-18_094812.csv >> postgresql.csv
```

I downloaded "pgbadger-11.2" and tried below command but getting error.

```
D:\pgbadger-11.2>perl --version
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

D:\pgbadger-11.2>perl pgbadger "D:\June-Logs\postgresql.csv" -o postgresql.html
[========================>] Parsed 923009530 bytes of 923009530 (100.00%), queries: 1254764, events: 53
can not load incompatible binary data, binary file is from version < 4.0.
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
```

postgresql.html is created but no data in any tab.But it works when i create separate report for individual csv. like below.

```
D:\pgbadger-11.2>perl pgbadger "D:\June-Logs\postgresql-2020-06-18_075333.csv" -o postgresql-2020-06-18_075333.html
D:\pgbadger-11.2>perl pgbadger "D:\June-Logs\postgresql-2020-06-18_080011.csv" -o postgresql-2020-06-18_080011.html
...
D:\pgbadger-11.2>perl pgbadger "D:\June-Logs\postgresql-2020-06-18_094812.csv" -o postgresql-2020-06-18_094812.html
```

Please suggest me something to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I going to say this due to:

```
type postgresql-2020-06-18_075333.csv > postgresql.csv
type postgresql-2020-06-18_080011.csv >> postgresql.csv
```

Pretty sure that is introducing Windows line endings and pgBadger is looking for Unix line endings. Can you do the concatenate on the server?

UPDATE. Hmm. Ran across this

https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/releases

"This new release breaks backward compatibility with old binary or JSON
files. This also mean that incremental mode will not be able to read
old binary file [...]  Add a warning about version and skip loading incompatible binary file.

- Update code formatter to pgFormatter 4.0."

Not sure why it is failing on CSV logs, still what is version of pgBadger generating logs?

Comment: Hi @Adrian. I gave it a try. I concatenated files on server by "cat postgresql-2020-06-18_080011.csv >> postgresql.csv" for all 80 files and transferred that big file to local. I verified the combining file with matching the line numbers and it was ok. I tried pgbadger for big file but getting same error again.

Comment: my pgBadger version is 11.2 which is latest one and perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread. as per document ,it looks like bug is fixed in 11.2 but i am still getting the error. It is not even giving any hint like line number, else i could have manged by loosing some records.

Comment: I'm at a loss for an explanation. The only I can think of is file an issue here: https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/issues